# Sorting by date from bad string field in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, sorting, date

I'm using an SQLite database in an app I'm developing with ionic, but unfortunately the database is built in such a way that the date fields are strings, not proper Date type values. (I'm not the person who's responsible for building this database, nor can I ask them to fix this). They all follow a `"DD-Mon"` format.

So the structure is as follows

```
id  |date    | (other columns...) 
1   |"25-Jan"|
2   |"25-Jan"|
3   |"30-Jan"|
4   |"30-Jan"|
5   |"31-Jan"|
6   |"31-Jan"|
7   |"31-Jan"|
8   |"31-Jan"|
#   (500 more rows like this)
```

The problem is that I want to use a query that only gets the dates from a certain day onwards (something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE /*(date after X)*/;`)

One thing to notice that might be helpful, although I still couldn't think of a solution, is that the IDs go from early to late, so if a given id X is greater than an id Y, then date X comes after date Y.

Comment: Do you "know" what year those dates belong to?

Comment: All of them are from 2015.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite doesn't have strong data typing in the SQL sense.

```
sqlite> create table test (dt date not null);
sqlite> insert into test values ('wibble');
sqlite> select * from test;
wibble
```

In your case, if you know the year, you can

- create a new table with the right structure,
- insert the corrected the data,
- verify it,
- drop the old table, and
- rename the new table.

Foreign keys can make this more troublesome, but it's still pretty straightforward.

**Create a new table**

Use whatever method you like. You might start with `.schema old-table-name`, for example, and give it a new table name.

**Insert the corrected the data, and verify it**

```
insert into new-table-name (id, date, other-columns)
select id, 
    '2015' || '-' ||
    case substr(dt, -3) 
    when 'Jan' then '01' 
    when 'Feb' then '02'
    when 'Mar' then '03'
    when 'Apr' then '04'
    when 'May' then '05'
    when 'Jun' then '06'
    when 'Jul' then '07'
    when 'Aug' then '08'
    when 'Sep' then '09'
    when 'Oct' then '10'
    when 'Nov' then '11'
    when 'Dec' then '12'
    end || '-' ||
    substr(dt, 1, 2) as date,
    ... -- other columns
from old-table-name;
```

**Drop the old table**

```
drop table old-table-name;
```

**Rename the new table**

```
alter table new-table-name rename to old-table-name;
```